# Loops in Excel VBA -- How do I iterate a function through a range?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

So I know Excel has an NPV function, but I'm trying to make my own since I'm trying to teach myself VBA. I have data laid out in a table and then I want to iterate through a horizontal range of cells (G5 through I5). The way I'm trying to structure the loop is by prompting for the number of cash flows and setting that number as the end date. This way the Macro can be used for problems with different durations.

My code is not working and I'm not sure why. Can someone take a look and help me out? Please use layman's terms as I just started with VBA yesterday.

```
Sub NPV()
Dim y As Integer, inv As Double, tax As Double, sal As Double, wc As Double, dr As Double, i As Integer, v As Double
y = Range("C4")
inv = Range("C5")
tax = Range("C6")
sal = Range("E4")
wc = Range("E5")
dr = Range("E6")

Dim total As Double
total = 0
For i = 1 To y
    v = Range("5, 5 + i")
    v = v / (1 + dr) ^ i
    total = total + v
    Next i

total = total + ((1 - tax) * sal) + wc
Range("F5").Value = total
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) how exactly it's not working, 2) what result do you expect here: `v = Range("5, 5 + i")`?

Comment: It just opens a window with the code with sub NPV highlighted. The result should be 8443. I think that the problem lies with that section of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Consider replacing:

```
v = Range("5, 5 + i")
```

with:

```
v = Cells(5, 5 + i)
```